# Correct approach to find derivative of : $f(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(x^3-4x)\sin(x^3-2x^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I have function:
$f(x) =  \operatorname{sgn}(x^3-4x)\sin(x^3-2x^2)$

which can be represented as:

$ f(x) = -\sin(x^3-2x^2) ;\quad x \in (-\infty, -2) \cup (0,2)$,

$ f(x) = \sin(x^3 - 2x^2); \quad x \in (-2, 0) \cup (2,\infty) $,

$f(x) = 0\quad$ if $x=-2\:$ or $\:x=0\:$ or  $\:x=2 $.

Therefore I have derivatives:

$ f(x)' = -\cos(x^3-2x^2)(3x^2-4) ;\quad x \in (-\infty, -2) \cup (0,2)$,

$ f(x)' = \cos (x^3 - 2x^2)(3x^2-4);\quad x \in (-2, 0) \cup (2,\infty) $,

$f(x)' = 0\quad$ if $x=-2\:$ or $\:x=0\:$ or  $\:x=2 $.

Is that correct? How can I find one sided derivatives, are there any?

Comment: what do you mean by one sided derivatives?And how did you get the derivatives for $x=-2~/~0~/~2$?

Comment: derivation in $-2^+$ for example, as the function is not continous in $-2$

Comment: so first of all lets check the derivativ in $x=2$, looking at the the Difference quotient we for $x>2$: $\frac{f(2)-f(x)}{2-x}=\frac{cos(x^3-2x^2)(3x^2-4)}{2-x}$. taking the limit on the right hand side for $x\to 2$, I dont think you will get $0$.

Comment: @Bara and I did get the derivatives for $x = -2 / 0 / 2 $ from the $f(x) = 0$ when $ x = -2 / 0 / 2  $ and therefore derivatives  of constant, in this case $0$ is equal to zero, right?

Comment: no this is not correct. Think of the following function:
$f(1) = 1$
and $f(x)=x~\forall~x\in(1,\infty)$ which is basicly the identiy. So by your argument we should have $f'(1)=0$ since it is "constant". But every function is constant in a single point. You allways need to take the difference quotient.

Comment: So what do you need to do in your case is the following: 
take the difference quotient $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(x+h)}{h}$ for some positiv $h$ and after that take the same Difference quotient for some negativ $h$. The second term i.e. $f(x+h)$ should depend on the sign of $h$ for $x=−2 / 0 / 2$
If the limit of the difference quotient for $h>0$ and $h<0$ is not the equal, then your function is not differentiable.

Comment: and can I use $f(a)' = \lim_{x->a} \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and in my case substitue a with $-2/0/2$?

Comment: well thats the definiton, so you should use that. Just make sure that the limit really exist for $x\to a$ when $x<a$ and for $x\to a$ when $x>a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin$ is continuous everywhere and $sgn$ is continuous everywhere except $x = 0$.  So $sgn(x^3-4x)\sin(x^3-2x^2)$ will be continuous everywhere except *maybe* where $x^3-4x = 0$.  i.e. everywhere except $x=-2,0,2$.

And yes, your calculations for $f'(x)$ are correct on all the points $x \ne [-2|0|2]$.

At $x= 0,2$ we have $x^3 - 2x^2 = 0$ so $\sin(x^3-2x^2) = 0$ so $\lim_{x\to [0|2]}sgn(x^3-4x)\sin(x^3-2x^2) = 0$ so $sgn(x^3-4x)\sin(x^3-2x^2)$ is continuous at $x = 0,2$.

But at $x = -2$ , $x^3 - 2x^2 = -16$ and $\sin(x^3-2x^2) = \sin(-16)=k \ne 0$.  $\lim_{x\to -2^+} sgn(x^3-4x)\sin(x^3-2x^2) = k$ and $\lim_{x\to -2^-} sgn(x^3-4x)\sin(x^3-2x^2)=-k$ so $f$ is not continuous at $x = -2$ and $f$ is not differentiable at $x = -2$.

So your result is incorrect in that $f'(-2)$ does not exist.

$f$ will be differentiable at $x = [0|2]$ if the left and right side limits of $f'$ are equal.

But $\cos(x^3-2x^2)(3x^2-4) = 1*(3x^2 - 4) = 8$ if $x = 2$ and $\cos(x^3-2x^2)(3x^2-4) = 1*(3x^2 - 4) = -4$ if $x = 0$.

So $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \cos(x^3-2x^2)(3x^2-4)= -4\ne 4 = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \cos(x^3-2x^2)(3x^2-4)$ and $\lim_{x\to 2^-} \cos(x^3-2x^2)(3x^2-4)=8\ne -8 = \lim_{x\to 2^+} \cos(x^3-2x^2)(3x^2-4)$.

so $f$ is not differentiable at $x = 0,2$.

===

You error is in assuming that as $f(x_1) = c$ a constant then $f'(x_1) = 0$.

By this reasoning I could assume if $f(x) = x^4$ then as $f(2) = 16$ then $f'(2) = 0$ which is obviously not correct.

For $f(x_1) = c$ to be a constant *function* and therefore $f'(x_1)= 0$ we must have $f(x) = c$ for *all* $x$ in an *interval* around $x_1$.